# princomp in R for PCA - Score variable in the output instance.

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, information-retrieval, pca

while using princomp R for PCA, score variable in the output instance say arc.pca in the given example contains the scores of the supplied data on the principal components. Is it the projection of the normalized data on the principal component or the actual data ?

```
data1 <- read.delim("file1",sep = "\t")
colnames(data1) <- c("v1","v2","a1", "a2", "l", "f", "d")
data2<-data.frame(data1$a1, data1$a2, data1$l, data1$f, data1$d)
arc.pca1 <- princomp(data2, scores=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
write(arc.pca1$scores,"datatext.score")
```

Answer (score 2):

the scores are the projections of the centered and standardized data on the reduced space, as you set `cor=TRUE` in the parameters of `princomp`.